# Parse query to select users created between 2 dates doesn't work

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to find users that were created between 2 dates. The query runs successfully but doesn't return any users. I have confirmed that there are plenty of users that were created b/w this date range though. I'mm running this query on cloud code. Any ideas on what's wrong? Would appreciate any help! 
Here's my query:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User); 
var startTime = new Date(2015, 7, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var endTime = new Date(2015, 7, 21, 0,0,0,0);
query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", startTime);
query.lessThan("createdAt", endTime); 
query.limit(1000);
query.find({...});
```

It isn't a permissions issue because this query works:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User); 
var d = new Date();
var oneday = (24 * 3600 * 1000);
query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", new Date(d.getTime() - oneday)); 
query.limit(1000);
query.find({...});
```

Comment: Users are created with privacy so that other users can't query them by Default. You will have to change the permissions on the user records or create another table to work alongside the users.

Comment: thanks @Fogmeister. I just updated my question - a different query on users works, so it can't be a permissions issue. I am running this on cloudcode too, so that's with the master key

Comment: You're so close to a good debugging technique.  Using the identical code, rerun except (1) comment out both date criteria, then (2) comment out just one criterion, then (3) comment out just the other criterion.  Examine the results for each and post here.